# Create array of arrays from object properties in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have to create an array of arrays based on some object attributes.

So my object looks like this:

```
const data = {
 projectId: 5,
 userIds: [2, 3, 1, 5],
 dateIds: [99, 100, 101, 102, 103], 
 task: 'task', 
 duration: 8, 
 description: 'description'
}
```

Based on the `userIds` and `dateIds` I have to create an array of arrays with every attribute like this:

`[[projectId, userId, dateId, task, duration, description]]` <- this is what every number means

For every `userId` and `dateId` i have to create a new array.

And based on my example should be like this:

```
[[5, 2, 99, 'task', 8, 'description'], 
[5, 3, 99 , 'task', 8, 'description'], 
[5, 1, 99, 'task', 8, 'description'], 
[5, 5, 99, 'task', 8, 'description'], 
[5, 2, 100, 'task', 8, 'description'], 
[5, 3, 100, 'task', 8, 'description'] 
... etc]]
```

Hope i explained my issue well. Thank you for your time!

My function:

```js
const data = { projectId: 5, userIds: [2, 3, 1, 5], date: [99, 100, 101, 102], task: 'task', duration: 'duration', description: 'description' }
    const parentArray = []
        data.date.map(object =>
            data.userIds.map(anotherObject => {
                // console.log(anotherObject, object)
                parentArray.push([data.projectId, object, anotherObject, data.task, data.duration, data.description])
            }
            ))
    console.log(parentArray)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried to map first by `userId` and then by `dateId` and somehow push them into a new array but it didn't worked

Comment: Are `userId` and `dateId` always guaranteed to be of the same length?

Comment: @painotpi no, they can have any length from 1 to n, but can never be empty

Comment: @poPaTheGuru please add the code you tried.

Comment: I see that here is working, totally my mistake guys, sorry for your time, found it was another problem. 
Sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const data = {
 projectId: 5,
 userIds: [2, 3, 1, 5],
 dateIds: [99, 100, 101, 102, 103], 
 task: 'task', 
 duration: 8, 
 description: 'description'
}

const result = data.userIds.map(uid => {
  return data.dateIds.map(did => [data.projectId, uid, did, data.task, data.duration, data.description])
}).flat();

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you asked for but using your example you can create an array of objects which might add clarity by naming the properties (if some other user needs something like this).   Note how I pass in the `data` and reference it with `this` and loop through the `dateId`'s.  Key is I never have to reference the original array, perhaps making this more maintainable internally;

```js
const data = {
  projectId: 5,
  userIds: [2, 3, 1, 5],
  dateIds: [99, 100, 101, 102, 103],
  task: 'task',
  duration: 8,
  description: 'description'
};
let x = [];
data.userIds.forEach(function(userid, index) {
  this.dateIds.map((dateid, idx) => {
    x.push({
      project: this.projectId,
      user: userid,
      dateid: dateid,
      tsk: this.task,
      dur: this.duration,
      desc: this.description
    });
  });
}, data);

x.forEach(function(el, index, array) {
  console.log(el);
});
```

Comment: Nice intervention. I needed just the array, without any description that's why I didn't added them :D